# Python loop collects data more than once and in weird order, what is going wrong?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am making a program to extract information out of some logs. The problem I am having is that I have a few loops to pick up different types of data on cluster nodes, but the loops all collect data on the nodes more than once and in a weird pattern. If I collect data on a 4 node cluster it will collect data in this order

1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4 instead of just having data for 1,2,3,4

here is a sample

```
def sysinfo_get(showall):
    for match in re.findall('<system-information-get for pnode[^<]+|', showall.read()):
        overview.append(match)

overview = []
healthfile = open('..\Healthcheck.txt', 'w+')

print('Collecting system info')
for path, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('-showall.txt'):
            showall = open(os.path.join(path, f), 'r')
            sysinfo_get(showall)
            for i in overview:
                healthfile.write(i)
```

Comment: Why are you writing your `overview` data *each time you find a matching file*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You repeatedly write the strings in the `overview` list to a file, always adding more entries to the list between writing. You end up with multiple copies of the data you added to that list.

The first time, `overview` is `['1']`. Next time, you append the next match, `'2'`, so now `overvier` contains `['1', '2']`. You write the whole list again. Then you append `'3'`, etc.

If you didn't want to write the previous matches, postpone writing the data until *after* you have completed the `os.walk()` loop, or set `overview` back to an empty list after writing.